# Android Eclipse Export Crashlytics Apk failed

Tags: crashlytics

I am trying to 'Export Crashlytics-enabled Android application' in eclipse and keep getting this error 'Problem Opening Wizard' with details - The selected wizard could not be started.
Cannot create extension
java.lang.NullPointerException

[image: Crashlytics Problem Opening Wizard]

How do resolve this issue? This was working perfectly fine until now and suddenly keep getting this issue. Tried several time to un-install crashlytics plug in and re-installing, it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete my entire workspace and create a new one to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between "Export Android Application" and "Export Crashlytics-enabled Android Application" ?

Answer (score 0):

I swas getting same problem. Restart ecllipse and wait till complete loading of external libs, folders etc.

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between "Export Android Application" and "Export Crashlytics-enabled Android Application" ?